# Macro to Save file within a file structure using cells as location

Tags: vba, excel, save

I have been trying to write a macro to save within a specific file location, the idea is the starting location is defined (This never changes), then there is a drop down list in cell B2 (This is a defined a folder Location) and another drop down list in cell B3 (This is a sub folder within the folder specified in B2) and then the file name in Cell B4.

The file location seems to get confused and defaults to `C:\My Documents` when running the macro.

As a test i removed the line 'Range "B3"' and it went to save the file in the correct folder location. Here is the current Macro:

```
Sub ThisFile()
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
"Macro Enabled Workbook" & "(*.xlsm), *xlsm", Title:=Range("B4") & ".xlsm", InitialFileName:="G:\New Manufacturing Engineering\Gear Shop\Spiral Bevel\Miscellaneous\Stock Removal Test File\Stock Removal Sheets\" & Range("B2") & "\" & Range("B3") & "\" & Range("B4") & ".xlsm")
With ActiveWorkbook
    On Error GoTo message
    .SaveAs varResult & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
    Exit Sub
message:
    MsgBox "There is an error"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps the path of the file is very tall?

Comment: Did you double check the string you are generating is for a directory that exists? The GetSaveAsFilename function seems like it will just default to My Documents instead of throwing an error if you provide an invalid path.

Answer (score 0):

OK so made a rookie mistake!! some of the titles from the drop down had spaces after hence no folders to locate!!!

The Macro above works perfectly